# Custom variables on variable products in woocommerce not showing in dropdown menu

Tags: woocommerce, frontend, product

I have a shop that is running woocommerce 3.1.2, the custom variables I have added to variable products, are not showing for around half of all product in the store.

According to a lot of similar topics it was a problem in woocommerce 3.0.5 and it was fixed in 3.0.6, yet it still appears here.

An example of the problem can be viewed here http://www.ventilatietechnologie.nl/product/iso-folie/

The theme that is used is flatsome (wordpress) and is updated to the latest version. All plugins have been updated to their latest versions and disabling them all and switching themes does not resolve this issue.

The custom variables also all have their prices filled in, so that cant be the cause. Does anyone have an inkling as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have added the custom attributes to the product but not the variations of that attribute (in your case size is custom attribute but the variations are not present in that attribute) so the drop down is showing empty field.
Try to add some variations of that attribute from product edit page where you have added the custom attribute(i.e size).
Thank you.